# Grunt Assemble is resolving relative paths in build files (want to keep relative paths)

Tags: gruntjs, relative-path, assemble

This is an interesting question, I've already searched Google so my hopes of reaching someone with an answer are slim.

I'm building a Grunt project, everything is great with my project except for one little thing I just noticed regarding relative paths **( ../../ )** when using the Assemble site generator. I am using a layout file in my project, fyi.

I need to use relative paths to link to files that are two levels lower than the root level of my Grunt project.  But when I run my build the output HTML is resolving the relative paths to root.

For example, my HTML code in the dev file...

```
<a href="../../hotels.html">Hotels</a>
```

is resolved to the following in the build file...

```
<a href="hotels.html">Hotels</a>
```

It completely ignores the **"../../"** when I need that relative path to stay. I eventually plan on dumping this build folder into another project and taking advantage of it's resources that reside two levels lower than this build.

Any help is appreciated.  So the gist of my questions... I want to maintain **"../../"** relative paths in my output HTML files after I run the Assemble task.

Here is the assemble task I've created...

```
assemble: {
    options: {
        layoutDir: './templates/layouts',
        data: './templates/app/json/**/*.{json,yml}',
        flatten: true
    },

    main: {
        options: {
            layout: './templates/layouts/default.html',
            partials: './templates/app/partials/**/*.html'
        },
        src: './templates/app/*.html',
        dest: './_build/'
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you please share the assemble options from your Gruntfile and describe your file layout of your assemble templates? Your dev file is an .hbs template?

Comment: Hi James, I've updated the above with the assemble task I've created.  I love it, works great other than it removing the relative linking from the HTML files in the build directory.

Comment: I found an issue here on the stack regarding the use of the grunt-usemin task, but usemin is a task runner that has many issues, including conflicts with uglify (so I don't want to use it) and it doesn't really apply to this issue.  Any help is appreciated.